# Difrrence between null and "" in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple if statement

```
if(variable == null)
```

does not enter the statement

```
if(variable == "")
```

does

Why does this happen?? 
What is the difference between "" and null in javascript

Comment: Why would you expect this to work in any language?

Comment: What's the actual value of that variable?

Comment: @deceze - if `variable == ''` evaluates to true then the value of *variable* might be an empty string, the number zero or boolean false, none of which will evaluate to true if compared with *null*.

Comment: The value of the variable is returned from a HTML form. I figured it would return null if the form is empty but it returns an empty string instead. Will the same value be returned if the field in form does not exist??

Comment: About the question in your comment, what would happen if the field doesn't exist will depend on how you are trying to get the value. If you want a meaningful answer to this new question post some more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`""` is the empty string. In other words, it's a string of length 0. `null` on the other hand is more like a generic placeholder object (or an object representing the absence of an object). There's also `undefined` which is different from both `""` and `null`.

But the point is, `"" != null` so therefore:

```
var s = "";
s == null; // false
s == ""; // true
```

Comment: The reason that *null* is only ever equal to *null* or *undefined* is because ECMA-262 says so.

Answer (score 2):

The ECMA–262 Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm (§ 11.9.3) says that `null == null` (step 1.b) or `null == undefined` (steps 2 and 3) return `true`, everything else returns false.

Answer (score 1):

There are types in JavaScript

typeof("") is "string" and typeof(null) is "object"

Comment: Yes, but do not get confused between an variable's *Type* and the value returned by the *typeof* operator, they are different things. While `typeof null` returns `object`, *null* is the *Null type*

Answer (score 1):

`""` is a string object with a length of zero.  `null` is the value the represents the absence of a value.  A string object is never null, regardless of its length.

Comment: I would have thought that *undefined* represents the absence of a value much better than *null*, particularly as declared variables that aren't assigned values evaluate to *undefined*, not *null*.

Comment: `null` means this identifier has no value.  `undefined` means this identifier does not exist.  There is a subtle but important difference there.

Comment: Squeegy — undefined absolutely **does not** mean an identifier "doesn't exist". `var a; alert(a);` shows undefined, yet *a* exists before the code executes—it just doesn't have a value. There are plenty of other examples.

Comment: Turns out the difference between undefined and null is hard to articulate :)

Answer (score 0):

As SHiNKiROU mentioned, there are types in Javascript. And since the language is dynamically typed, variables can change type. Therefore, even though your variable may have been pointing to, say, an empty string at some point, it may be changed to point to, say, a number now. So, to check the concept of "nonexistence" or "nothingness" or "undefinededness" of a variable,  Crockford recommends against doing stuff like `if (variableName == null)`.

You can take advantage of javascript's dynamically-typed qualities. When you want to check for a variable's "falsiness" or "nothingness", instead of `if(variableName == null)` (or `undefined` or `""`) use `if(!variableName)`

Also, instead of `if(variableName != undefined)` (or `null` or `""`) use `if(variableName)`

Comment: so if(variableName) will return true if variable isnt undefined null or "" and if it is it will return false??

Comment: Exactly. Your list is also missing the number 0.

Comment: Thats great :) do you know if any other languages have it like that like C++ or Java or is it very specific to javascript

Comment: You should only use `if (variableName)` where you are expecting the value to not be falsey. You can't use it reliably to detect the existence of a property or variable.